# RegEx Filter Works In RegExr But Not Logstash Grok

Tags: regex, logging, logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to filter the loglevel for some log files that I have. My issue is that Grok seems unable to handle `\w` being at the start of the filter.

I am using this site to verify regex: https://regexr.com/

I am using this site to test the Grok filter: http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Here is my example log line: 2020-04-07T13:08:19.261-0700|INFO |||

Here is what I am trying to run:

```
(?<timestamp>.+?(?=\|))(?<loglevel>\w+?(?= \|))
```

This says NO MATCHES found. If I replace the "\w" with "." it finds the line immediately, but leaves the non-alpha character:

```
{
  "timestamp": [
    [
      "2020-04-07T13:08:19.261-0700"
    ]
  ],
  "loglevel": [
    [
      "|INFO"
    ]
  ]
}
```

It *should* by all means work. Its just saying match \w characters. I am clearly lacking in regex knowledge here. Does anybody know what is going on and is willing to throw a few pointers my way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex does not match the string correctly because the `(?=\|)` is a non-consuming pattern and the pattern fails to match a space after timestamp with `\w`.

You may fix your current pattern with

```
(?<timestamp>.+?)\|(?<loglevel>\w+) \|
                 ^^                ^^^
```

The fields are created with the named group captures anyway, so you need no lookarounds here.

Note you may actually use

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\|%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}
```

to parse your current input.

Comment: Thank you! You have saved me money on migraine medication. I hope you and everybody you care about stays healthy.